# SignalR Client Internal Server Error 500

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I have use SignalR Demo from [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b/view/Discussions)

After having the server started. I try to sign-in to the client and I get the following error. Could you please let me know if there is something that I have done wrong.

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

{

  Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 03:02:41 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 0

}
```

But when i use `netstat -aon|findstr 8080`, the Service is running ok, just the client can't connect to the signalR server！

The client connect code:

```
/*This is client to connect the server*/

private async void ConnectAsync()
{
    Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
    Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;
    HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
    //Handle incoming event from server: use Invoke to write to console from SignalR's thread
    HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) =>
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, name, message))
        ))
    );
    try
    {
        Connection.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        await Connection.Start();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        StatusText.Text = "Unable to connect to server: Start server before connecting clients.";
        //No connection: Don't enable Send button or show chat UI
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatusText.Text = "ErrorCode 500, Internal Server Error: " + ex.ToString();
        return;
    }

    //Activate UI
    SignInPanel.Visible = false;
    ChatPanel.Visible = true;
    ButtonSend.Enabled = true;
    TextBoxMessage.Focus();
    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText("Connected to server at " + ServerURI + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

When client connect to ServerURI, it will cause the exception:ErrorCode 500, Internal Server Error

Comment: can you check if the apppool under which the serverside app runs is running ? Generally 500 error is caused by AppPool being off

Comment: This is literally a copy/paste of a question on the link from the OP. The person who asked that question answered their own issue saying they had an incorrect port.

Comment: Thanks very much! I’ve really had a similar problem like the link. But my port is correct, because I've change the port, it still have the problem.

Comment: the demo is a C/S program, i'am not understand how to set AppPool